# Search Wordpress media with Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, livesearch

For testing purposes I want to search through the media of the featured image in Wordpress. But it seems I can't activate the search through a JavaScript action.

The search DOM on the admin page is:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search media..." id="media-search-input" class="search">
```

I can change the value of the input field with:

```
// input text string
document.getElementById('media-search-input').value = "test string";
```

After changing the input value, no search is being done. I guess I have to trigger the search somehow, But I don't know how?

It seems I can't trigger the search with .click(), .focus() or .blur(). There's also no button to hit because WP has a live search functionality.

Comment: We have no clue what triggers the search. Did you try submitting the form? Did you try to trigger keypress, down, up, input?

Comment: I have no clue either. Normally if you type in a key, you get a result.

Comment: so trigger a keydown, keyup, or keypress event and see if it works.

Comment: If change() does not trigger anything on a search box, I would suspect a missing library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So try to trigger keyboard events (keydown, keyup, keypress)

```
var elem = document.querySelector("#media-search-input");
var kpEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Enter', keyCode: 13 });
elem.dispatchEvent(kpEvent);
```

or try input event

```
var event = new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
});

elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Thanks Epascarello, but the dispatchEvent function has been cancelled. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) I'll read the documentation in the meanwhile. Sorry; I'm a beginner.

Comment: cancelled? Huh? Are you referring to the variable name that tells you the result of the event?

Comment: Really odd, the console said that dispatchevent was cancelled. I reloaded the entire page and your solution is working when I paste it line by line. Guess something went wrong on copy/paste. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Dug around and found this:

```js
wp.media.frames.browse.state().get('library')._requery(true)
```